# Control User Permission in C# windows application

Tags: c#, sql, windows, permissions

I already designed Windows app with C# and SQL 2008.
Now ,I want to control that user can access to which part and its permissions.

So, I want to know is it better to design table in sql and set the permissions for each user or there are any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, what I have seen is something along the following lines:

Have a `tblUser` table something like this:

```
tblUser
    UserId
    UserName
    etc...
```

A roles table:

```
tblRole
    RoleId
    Name
```

And a linker table:

```
tblUserRole
    UserId
    RoleId
```

In your application, you would check to see if the current user has the respective role in the `tblUserRole` table. If so, allow the current user to use the feature, else display an error message, disallow the user entry etc...

In `MS SQL` for instance, you could have the following types of `Stored Procedure`:

**Add User**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddUser
    @UserName AS nvarchar(256)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO tblUser
    (UserName)
    VALUES(@UserName)

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY( ) AS 'Id'
END
GO
```

**Add User Role**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddUserRole
@UserId AS int,
@RoleId As int
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO tblUserRole
    (UserId, RoleId)
    VALUES(@UserId, @RoleId)
END
GO
```

**Does User Have Role**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDoesUserHaveRole
@UserId AS int,
@RoleId As int,
@HasRole AS bit OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @HasRole = COUNT(UserId) > 0 FROM tblUserRole
    WHERE UserId = @UserId AND
          RoleId = @RoleId
END
GO
```

Comment: is there any solution by using sql ? I mean creating user in sql for each app user and define access level?

Comment: @franchescototti The above answer is in SQL. All of the data is stored in SQL. The actual check can be in a `SPROC` or within your code respectively.

Comment: @franchescototti I have updated my answer with some sample SQL